# Converting 3V3 PWM to 5V analog

Tags: analog, pwm, level-shifting, conversion

I want to convert a 3V3 PWM (10 kHz) signal to a 0-5V analog DC signal using transistors only (no DAC), if possible. The output logic should be non-inverted, i.e. 0V->0V and 3V3->5V. The time constant of the conversion should be <20 ms.

Which circuit topology could be used to achieve this?

EDIT: I have a 5V supply available.

Comment: Can you use an op amp?

Comment: Microchip TB3250 - [Using PWM to Generate Analog Output](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/90003250A.pdf)

Comment: @Drew - I could yeah, but I am not sure whether it could be achieved without it. The precision of the conversion could be within 5-10% so...

Comment: @ErikR - Thanks. That is certainly one way of doing it.

Comment: Use a circuit called a **level shifter** or **level translator**. You can do that with a couple of transistors and resistors or use a levelshifter/translator IC for that.

Comment: Level convert 3.3V PWM to 5V PWM and then RC filter it to analog?

Comment: 74HCT family works with “1” >= 2V input on 5V out

Comment: I agree with Justme and Tony. Use a logic gate followed by an RC. If you absolutely don't want to use any IC, you can still do it with transistors but you will just need a few more of them. A 20ms time constant implies a cutoff frequency of 8 Hz. Should be no problem to remove 10 kHz with an 8 Hz low-pass filter.

Answer (score 10):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkpF9w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The [74HCT1G125](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT1G125.pdf) buffers and level-shifts the 3.3V to 5V (Vdd should be +5) and the RC filter converts the 5V PWM to analog with a sub-mV p-p ripple and rise time less than 20ms.

[image]

Comment: Or a second inverter.

Comment: @mkeith Good catch, thanks. Modified.

Comment: I assume the output signal has pretty high impedance, they might want to buffer the final output voltage with a general purpose rail-to-rail opamp

Comment: @Finbarr LOL. Sure one more inverter would do. Or 3 more. Or 5 more. But non-inverting buffers are available in the same logic family and footprint so...

Comment: @KyranF - I would adjust the output resistance to be <1k and do a compromise over ripple AND/OR increase the switching frequency.

Comment: Probably best to buffer the output with a rail-to-rail op-amp. Otherwise the internal resistance of the buffer will start to adversely affect the linearity. But your requirements are very fuzzy so hard to tell. If you drove a pair of MOSFETs with an inverter (or another pair) you could do it directly without a buffer and lower resistors/bigger caps but there would be some other downsides such as some shoot-through current and some ripple due to layout most likely.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - 74HCT has the worst case of Vin_h as 3.15 under 4.5V VDD. That seems edgy.

Comment: @Bip The datasheet I linked has both 74HC and 74HCT.  You'll find the HCT numbers on page 5. For Vcc between 4.5 and 5.5VDC the minimum is 2.0V and typical is 1.6V. Plenty of margin.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - gotcha, thanks! Do you have any link where I can read more about the linearity effect that you mentioned when using 74HCT with a resistor in series in <1k range? Thank you.

Comment: I suggest simulating it and playing with the values, either in Circuitlab or (as I did) in LTspice (free download). Intuitively, if it charges with one resistance value and discharges with another, the value at mid-scale will be different from 50%.

Answer (score 9):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuNraS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

the conversion is not perfectly linear, but this improves the more that R2 has higher resistance than R1.

M1 is some mosfet that switches at less than 3V

For < 20ms time constant satisfy the inequation (R1+R2)C1 < 20mS

Comment: Very neat, I may implement something like this! Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain this thing about "non-linearity" regarding the R1 and R2?

Comment: If we assume that the FET and the signal source are ideal, then the speed of charge is set by R1+R2 but the speed of discharge is set by R2 only. So rather than the mean output voltage being 5V*Th</sub>/(Th+Tl) it's 5V*(Th/(R1+R2))/((Th/(R1+R2))+(Tl/R2)).

Answer (score 6):

Since there is 5V supply available, one solution would be to use a logic gate to convert 3.3V PWM signal to 5V PWM signal, and then RC filter the 5V PWM signal to analog with the requirement of the 20ms time constant.

The logic gate would have to be suitable for accepting 3.3V levels at input while being powered at 5V to provide 5V output. One suitable type out of many is the HCT logic family.